# How to fix image texture not transfering to Unity from Blender

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, png, textures, blender

I textured an object in Blender because it wouldn't texture properly in Unity, and then imported the object and texture to Unity.

I don't know how to fix this, I'll put both pictures here.

[Blender Texture Before Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAjt7.png)

[Object In Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZwvX.png)

Comment: Have you made sure the texture was in the same folder as the textured model when importing into unity? Also, have you tried just dragging the texture onto your model in unity?

Comment: I've tried both, the issue is that the texture is already on it, but it's not rapping around properly in unity (I have the nodes set up in blender to fix the issue, but it wont transfer to unity)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and their linked pages. Don't apologize for being new or inexperienced; we don't care. What we care about is that you've done your due diligence and created a well-asked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so based on your screenshots..

1. You're going to select everything then add a modifier called "Solidify", then set this to something very small like .03. (Unity doesn't like objects that are just planes).

   **double check all your normals are facing out. Let me know if you don't know how to do this...**
2. Go into edit mode select all edges, then right click, select "mark as seam".
3. Open UV editor window (should be split screen with Edit mode on one side, UV view on the other). In the Edit side select all, then go to UV dropdown menu and click "unwrap". You should then see your object unfolded into flat planes over on the UV window side. There's different unwrap options, like smart UV unwrap, etc. I think just "unwrap" has worked for me, but play around and there may be something that shows your object shapes in a less distorted way..
4. At this point, since your pattern is basically repeating. If you export the OBJ file and take it into unity, and you add the image file (make sure it's dimensions are perfectly square) it should receive the image file as an Albedo texture much better than in your screenshots. You can play with the 'tiling' and "X/Y offset" till it looks right (you might face issues with rotation though.

BUT

5. If you want to line it up very specifically, you can export the UV layout as a png from the UV window in blender. Then use photoshop or another photo editor to change/rotate and arrange your texture so the sides line up properly. In blender in the Edit window (assuming you still have both UV + editor open) when you select a side it will highlight in the UV window the corresponding flat plane, based on this you should be able to figure out what should be rotated up/down, etc. Then when you change that 2d image and drag it into Unity, it will adjust and wrap around the object.

Comment: thank you, i did the seams thing and it fixed the texture, and even made it look better than it did in blender

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to both, but the advice I've been given is to not do the texturing in blender, but instead to do it in Unity.

Comment: I tried but it didn't rap around properly, that's why I had to do it in blender

Comment: Have you done UV mapping, marked the seam, unwrapped, etc? You can maybe play around with the tiling, and offset values in unity as well

Answer (score 0):

This is a 10-month-old post but incase anyone is curious or struggling the same, Blender exports models with a scale of 100 so you need to scale up the tile of the material (in material settings) to see it.

This is a bad solution however because then you are not working with objects on a scale of 1 so you actually want to check "Apply transformations" when exporting the FBX model in blender